# Writing flows using accounts in corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am using accounts in Corda. New accounts are creating successfully in my code but, I am facing difficulties in doing these two things.
1.) How to check if account is actually created and is present in the node, means if we can check the list of all the accounts in Corda.

2.) How to write responder flow for accounts, means My transaction flow is not working properly. Is there anything to change in the responder flow classic code if we now start using the accounts library?

My Code is as follows :

```
@InitiatedBy(Proposal.class)
public static class ProposalAcceptance extends FlowLogic<Void> {

    //private variable
    private FlowSession counterpartySession;

    //Constructor
    public ProposalAcceptance(FlowSession counterpartySession) {
        this.counterpartySession = counterpartySession;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public Void call() throws FlowException {
        SignedTransaction signedTransaction = subFlow(new SignTransactionFlow(counterpartySession) {
            @Suspendable
            @Override
            protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) throws FlowException {
                /*
                 * SignTransactionFlow will automatically verify the transaction and its signatures before signing it.
                 * However, just because a transaction is contractually valid doesn’t mean we necessarily want to sign.
                 * What if we don’t want to deal with the counterparty in question, or the value is too high,
                 * or we’re not happy with the transaction’s structure? checkTransaction
                 * allows us to define these additional checks. If any of these conditions are not met,
                 * we will not sign the transaction - even if the transaction and its signatures are contractually valid.
                 * ----------
                 * For this hello-world cordapp, we will not implement any aditional checks.
                 * */
            }
        });
        //Stored the transaction into data base.
        subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(counterpartySession));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Account internally are simply corda states of type `AccountInfo`, so you could query the vault to list all accounts the node knows about using:

   `run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo`
2. There isn't anything specific that changes in the responder flow, please make sure you are using the correct sessions in the initiator flow. Take a look at few of the samples available in the samples repository here: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Accounts

Comment: Thank You so much Ashutosh, This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- To check that an account was created, you need to write flow tests; a great way to learn is to look at how R3 engineers conduct their tests.
- For instance, you can find [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/test/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/test/CreateAccountFlowTests.kt) the test scenarios for `CreateAccount` flow.
- To get an account, the library has a very useful service `KeyManagementBackedAccountService` with different methods to get an account (by `name`, `UUID`, or `PublicKey`); have a look [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/services/KeyManagementBackedAccountService.kt).
- Now regarding requesting the signature of an account, one thing that is important to understand is that it's not the account that signs the transaction, it's the node that `host`s the account that signs on behalf of the account.
- So let's say you have 3 nodes (A, B, and C); A initiates a flow and requests the signature of 10 accounts (5 are hosted on B, and 5 are hosted on C).
- After A signs the initial transaction it will create `FlowSession`s to collect signatures.
- Since it's the `host` nodes that sign on behalf of accounts, then in our example you only need 2 `FlowSession`s; one with node B (so it signs on behalf of the 5 accounts it hosts) and one session with node C (for the other 5 accounts).
- In the responder flow nodes B and C will receive the transaction that was signed by the initiator.
- Out of the box, when a node receives a transaction it looks at all of the required signatures and for each required signature if it owns the private key; it will provide that signature.
- Meaning, when node B will receive the transaction; it will see 10 required signatures, and because it hosts 5 of the accounts (meaning it owns the private keys for those 5 accounts), then it will automatically provide 5 signatures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Adel, Your explanation and resources helped me a lot to understand the concepts better

Comment: But, I have a little doubt here which is that if nodes sign the transaction on behalf of the accounts then what if every account wants to have different preferences to check the transaction and accept the transaction. Or in simple words, is it possible for individual account to impose it's own checks on the transactions. Is that possible in any way?

Comment: The general rule is that every responding node should implement its own version of the responder flow; I guess you can make it more granular and add some logic that checks the requested signature (`PublicKey`) and you fetch the related account, then based on that account `name` (or `UUID`) you'll have some business logic...but that would create a lot of mess in my opinion.

Comment: I think a better approach (more clean) is to use the new `Business Networks and Memberships` extension that was added with Corda 4.6; you can read about it in my article [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/whats-new-and-exciting-in-corda-4-6-9e41d1d40f31). Make sure to check the references section for some informational videos on the topic.

Comment: Now, I got the solution comletely. Thank you very Much, Adel.